# Which Files Does boot-repair Copy To Windows?

Tags: boot-repair

After re-sizing and moving some partitions around with GParted from a Live USB I was dropped to grub rescue.

I used boot-repair to re-install grub but I ended up with 2 entries for Windows 10 [like this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/341114/why-does-grub-report-two-items-for-windows-7).

Previously I only had one entry and Windows booted fine.

I can currently boot into Ubuntu but neither Windows option from grub gets me to my Windows desktop.

If I boot from the second entry (main Windows partition) it says winload.exe is missing or corrupt (the file does exist so maybe the latter).

If I boot from the first entry (system reserved partition), Windows appears to boot (the Windows boot logo appears and it seems to boot) but then I am left with a black screen with a mouse pointer instead of the login screen.

Windows startup repair can't fix it.

I suspect that the files that boot-repair has copied to the Windows partitions have made them appear corrupt to Windows 10.

What is the list of files that boot-repair copies to Windows?

Comment: That is not how I remember boot repair works. Boot repair copies files FROM the OS to an EFI partition.  ALSO take not that boot-repair has a community that helps. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair on how to create a link (in the form of `paste.ubuntu.com/XXXXXX`) where the boot repair people can examine what is happening.

Comment: It says repair Windows boot files in the gui options.

Comment: Never select this if your system is booting, it copies the boot files from the (seemingly useless) 100MB "System Reserved" Partition to your "main" Partition.  Now GRUB finds you can boot from either and gives you two entries, yes you can suppress one.  Windows update might want that partition to behave as it expects it to. You can get rid of it at your peril but the next Windows update may complain...